# Can i use "Figma" Instead of HTML,CSS

Tags: html, css, figma

Can I design sites with figma instead of writing them in html + css? Only design.

Comment: It depends on what the stakeholder wants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**YES**

As far as you are just talking about prototyping, you can do it in Figma with animations as an addon. You can share your figma prototype for review purposes too.

However, Figma doesn't give you an HTML, CSS code that you can host on your server so you will have to code it at the end to make it available online.

Hope this will clear your thoughts about figma.